# Non-Hamiltonian Graphs with Disjoint Perfect Matchings?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I'm looking for non-Hamiltonian graphs with 2 (or more) disjoint perfect matching. Every graph I can think of that obeys one property but fails the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.  Two disjoint perfect matchings are $(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)$ and 
$(1,4),(2,3),(5,6),(7,8)$.

[image]